# How can I fake a class instance using an object (and still have flowtype verify the interface)?

Tags: javascript, typing, flowtype

I have

```
class A {
   func() {}
}
```

if in my tests I now create a fake (or double) for it, which fulfills the same interface, so I can inject this into some place I want to test, e.g. like this

```
const fakeAInstance = { func: () => void 0; }
```

flowtype will complain in the following that types are incompatible, one is an object (my fake) and the other is an instance of `class A`

```
 const toBeTested = (a: A) => {}

 const testFunction = () => { toBeTested(fakeAInstance) };
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is an object, not of type `A`
```

Creating fakes like that is much easier for testing, esp. when it gets more complex. Is there a way *without* turning of the type checking?

Comment: I think this is incorrect, right? `{ func: () => void 0; }` should be `{ func: () => 0, }`

Answer (score 0):

If your `toBeTested` function actually needs an instance of a class, then you have to provide it. If it only relies on it's interface, you should declare it's type and use it as annotation instead:

```
type T = {
  func(): void
}

 const toBeTested = (a: T) => {}
```

You can still use a class to implement type `T`:

```
const instance: T = new A();
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually if I need to create fakes for testing I just cast through `any` (which is unsafe, but hey, it's a test):

```
const fakeAInstance: A = (({ func: () => 0 }): any)
```

This way, you still get typechecking everywhere except in this one spot. Elsewhere, Flow believes that `fakeAInstance` has type `A`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use interface, which works both for classes and objects:

```
interface MyIntf {
  func(): void;
}

class A {
  func(): void {}
}

class B extends A {}

const o = {func: ():void => undefined};

function f(val: MyIntf) {
  val.func();
}

f(o);

f(new A());

f(new B());
```

it passes for me, as of flow-0.36